# Strings in C Issues

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I'm wondering what the difference is between

```
char* str[NUM];
char str[NUM];
char* str;
```

My understanding is that an array definition such as the one in the middle points to the address of the first value, that is `str[0]`. But I also see the notation represented by the first line of code, that is, a pointer to an array. Are these three equivalent? I'm aware the array definition sets space in the stack for `NUM` characters so is that probably better than just

```
char* str?
```

Thanks

Comment: The sky is *not* made of bricks. The first line is *not* a pointer to an array.

Comment: [Arrays and pointers are not the same thing](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: @KerrekSB I was hoping to hear something more useful as to what it actually is saying, an array of pointer to char types, but I found that elsewhere. What I was confusing was the idea that a pointer can point to the memory address of an array and therefore use the same operations as if it were initialized as such.

Comment: This is what makes sense: "As Wayne Throop has put it, it's `pointer arithmetic and array indexing [that] are equivalent in C, pointers and arrays are different.')"

Comment: @alvarezcl: That's because an object is identified by the *pair* (type, address). Two different objects can have the same address as long as they have a different type, as is the case for the array and the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* str[NUM];
```

This is an array of `NUM` `char` pointers

```
char str[NUM];
```

This is an array named `str` which is `NUM` `char`s long.

```
char *str;
```

This is a pointer to type `char`

Comment: For the last one, `str` is a pointer *to* type `char`, or equivalently a pointer of type `char*`. I know that's what you meant, but it's not what "This is a pointer of type `char`" says.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* str[NUM];
```

- An Array with NUM elements.  Each element is a pointer-to-character(s).
  In common terms, this is likely an array of strings.
  `str[0]` is the first string.
  `str[1]` is the second string, etc, etc.
  Any element of this array may be NULL.

---

```
char str[NUM];
```

- An array with NUM elements.  Each element is an individual character.
  In common terms, this is a fixed-size string of length NUM-1.
  (the last position is for the string null-terminator)
  This string cannot be NULL.  It can be empty (""), but it always exists.

---

```
char* str;
```

- A pointer to characters(s).
  In common terms, this is a string, of no particular fixed size.  You'll find the end of the string when you find the null-terminator.
  This string can be NULL, and not point to any memory.

Comment: No, the first case is not an array of strings. It may be an array of *pointers to* strings, depending on the actual values of the elements. A string is a sequence of characters; a string cannot be a pointer.

Comment: I wrote, "In ***common terms***, this is ***likely*** an array of strings".  I still feel that is an accurate approximation to aid in understanding.

Comment: That may be an accurate statement, but if so it merely implies that "common terms" are wrong. A string is not a pointer. The false idea that arrays are really pointers is one of the biggest and most common misconceptions about C. Please don't propagate it further.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* str[NUM];
```

Declares `str` as array of `num` pointers to `char`s.

```
char str[NUM];
```

Declares `str` as array of `num` `char`s.

```
char* str;
```

Declares `str` as pointer to a `char`.

You can test these type of declarations [here](http://cdecl.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
char* str1[NUM]; // an array of size NUM of pointers to char
char str2[NUM];  // an array of size NUM of char
char* str3;      // a pointer to char
```

Uses of these might be:

```
str1[NUM-1] = strdup("foo");
strcpy(str2, "foo");
str3 = strdup("foo");
```

Comment: Isn't the size equal to `NUM` instead of `N`?

Comment: Yep. Sorry about that.